# Where can I get cURL libraries?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I need the source code for the cURL libraries, but the website that hosts the code, curl.haxx.se, has been down for quite some time. Is downloading it from a place like sourceforge.com safe?

Comment: If you have a unix-like, search in the package manager.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party resource reliability

Comment: @alko, I disagree about this being off topic, at least for the reason given.  If the question was "What's the best library for making HTTP requests?" then certainly this quotation would apply.  There is nothing subjective about this question however.  The official website for a specific library is no longer available.  Whether or not it exists in other locations is a matter of fact, not opinion.

Comment: @bcrist StackOverflow is a place to ask specific programming questions. The question is if downloading the source from website x is safe (or reliable?). Everyone can have an opinion about that, and everyone can have a different definition of 'safe', and that definition can even change in a different context. An answer to this question will always be opinionated. The close reason is close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sourceforge project doesn't contain any files as far as I can tell, however there is this Github repository, which seems to be quite active:

https://github.com/bagder/curl

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't checked there yet.